# Losing data from string after passing input

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to write data to an object that contains names and numbers, but for some reason, the name loses it's data right after initializing it with with the `Scanner` (this is all called within a method called `private void addPerson()`)**.**

```
    String addName = "Just an empty String."; 
    System.out.println(addName + " testing");  // (Just an empty String. testing)
    System.out.println("Name: ");       
    addName = input.nextLine(); 
    System.out.println(addName); // null no matter what is entered
    input.next();
    System.out.println(addName + " again"); // Still null ( again)
```

Right after input a name, I tried to see if the name was stored, but it doesn't. The first print doesn't even register in the output. The next thing to be displayed after I had hit ENTER was the last line, but it on displayed " again" in the output screen. The reason I have `input.next()` is because without it, the program will print everything up until I'm asking for input for integers. Even when I set the String to a default text, after trying to change it to a different name by means of user input, the String becomes null right after.

Lastly, when I perform the same test for the integers, they work perfectly.

Any suggestions as to what may be causing my String to not store anything?

Comment: Please post more detailed code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you declare the variable `input`?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

For printing the `addName` again, change it to

```
addName = input.next();
System.out.println("2. addName: " + addName);
```

Comment: That fixed the problem I was having. Don't know why it wasn't a problem until now, because I haven't been doing much of anything differently in my past projects. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I think the *problem* is in [nexLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29), here is the documentation:

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that
>   was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line,
>   excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the
>   beginning of the next line.
>
> Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a
>   line separator, it may buffer all of the input searching for the line
>   to skip if no line separators are present.
>
> Returns:
>       the line that was skipped

Perhaps you may use [next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29)?